# Tricks on Computing limsup of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence $\{p_n\}$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_n$ is defined as the $\sup$ of the set of all subsequential limits.

A very simple case is $p_n = 1$ if $n$ is odd, and $0$ if even. In this case we can imagine a subsequence that's the odd values, so that $\limsup p_n = 1$.

Conceptually it makes sense, but I am having trouble actually computing limsups.

For example, consider $p_n = (\frac{2^n}{n!})^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Could you share some general tips or tricks to actually computing limsups?

---

Edit:

For future readers, the concept of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ is commonly introduced/defined as taking the supremum of all subsequential limits. A more intuitive way of thinking of this for me is to consider $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \sup_{m\geq n} p_m \right)$$
where we may think of $\sup_{m\geq n} p_m$ as the "tail" behavior of the sequence as it grows. For example consider the sequence
$$ p_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} \ (n \ \text{even}) \\ 0 \ (n \ \text{odd}) \end{cases} $$
There are many possible subsequences here. However as $n$ grows, we know the supremum of the truncated sequence from $n$ onwards is getting smaller and smaller to $0$. Thus this is one alternative way of thinking about and computing $\limsup$.

Comment: There is no $\limsup$ involved in computing the limit of $p_n$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat. My question is specifically on computing the $\limsup$ of $p_n$, not the limit.

Comment: They are the same thing (since the limit exists). In any event, the $\limsup$ is just the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} p_k$.

Answer (score 1):

The technique for showing that the limsup of a sequence is $L$ would be something like this:

1. Find a subsequence $\{p_{n_k}\}_k$ that converges to $L$.
2. Find an upper-bounding sequence $\{u_n\}_n$ such that $u_n \geq p_n$ for all $n$ and $u_n \rightarrow L$.

Now, it's actually not so common to have to evaluate limsups.
Their main utility is to make statements like:

> Since $p_n \leq U$ for all $n$, we have that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_n \leq U$.

We can't make such statements about limits, since the corresponding limit may not exist, but the limsup does always exist, so such statements can be made safely without spending energy trying to prove convergence.